lit() only populates the first row of the column
Spark newbie here trying to get AWS Glue to add columns to my dataset.
In particular, I have the following Spark code
df = s3SourceDataDynamicFrame.toDF()
df = df.select(
    col("eventId").cast("string").alias("nodeId:ID(ABCD)"),
    lit("ABCD").cast("string").alias("nodeType:String"),
    ...
)
...
df.write \
  .format("parquet") \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .save("some S3 location")

However, the nodeType:String column only has the value ABCD for the first row. Every other column is null.
No problems with the nodeId:ID(ABCD) column.
What's more confusing is that I have other jobs where lit() is doing what it's supposed to.
What am I missing???
P.S. The following also gave me the same result
df = s3SourceDataDynamicFrame.toDF()
df = df.select(
    col("eventId").cast("string").alias("nodeId:ID(ABCD)"),
    ...
)
df = df.withColumn("nodeType:String", lit("ABCD").cast("string"))
...
df.write \
  .format("parquet") \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .save("some S3 location")


It looks like the actual issue is with the parquet viewer I was using.
I was loading a .snappy.parquet compressed file, which, I'm assuming, uses run-length encoding to store only one copy of a value that is repeated across a column.
However, the parquet viewer (presumably) wasn't decompressing the file; hence, I saw null values for the entire column (vs. the same literal value repeated all the way through)
Reading (and previewing) the DataFrame with Pandas showed that the column is indeed getting generated as expected
